# Go: Format timestamp to default postgres format

Tags: postgresql, go

How do I make the timestamp format:

```
2015-01-25T22:22:46+08:00
```

look like this

```
2015-01-25T22:22:46.923331Z
```

To get the first format, I used

```
time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
```

The second format is the default postgres format that I'm trying to duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z"` as the format instead. It's just `RFC3339` with decimals added.

Comment: still didn't get this part: 923331Z

Comment: It didn't? It works for me: http://play.golang.org/p/CsEZfbnz_b  gives `2015-01-25T15:47:58.411372Z`